# Filter list o objects into servlet context in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a list of object into the application context and I want to filter this list to get only one element to display jsp page. I tried to filter the list using a stream-filter function:

```
<c:set var="itemDetalias" value="${applicationScope.productList.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == item.getProductId()).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()).get(0)}" />
```

but I have this error msg:

`${applicationScope.productList.stream().filter( ppp -> ppp.getId() == item.getProductId()).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()).get(0)}'`
`Method not found: class org.apache.el.stream.Stream.collect(null)`

How could I filter the list ?

Comment: Put that code into a controller servlet. And use findFirst()/findAny() rather collecting to a list.

Comment: @JBNizet is there any way to do the filter using jstl ?

Comment: Sure. But it's also possible to hit nails with a screwdriver. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution. Tomcat has its [own stream library](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/el/stream/Stream.html) which has some functions like `filter`, but it does not have `collect` function. Instead of using the `collect` function, use the `toList` function.

The new line should be:

```
<c:set var="itemDetalias" value="${applicationScope.productList.stream().filter(p -> p.getId() == item.getProductId()).toList().get(0)}" />
```