# How do I use Collectors#joining in EL Stream API?

Tags: tomcat, java-stream, el

I'm trying to print in a JSP the contents of a list as a single String separated by commas.

```
<div>${myList.stream().map(e->e.getStringValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))}</div>
```

I get the error:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class org.apache.el.stream.Stream.collect(null)
```

Why is Tomcat using it's own version of `Stream`?
Is there a way to avoid this and make sure that what I write in my java classes will have the same behavior when I put them in EL in a JSP?

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42930628/2761418
But it doesn't solve my problem. It uses custom method of Tomcat Streams.

Answer (score 8):

The EL Stream API is not tied to Java 8's Stream API. The EL stream API is an entirely standalone API which was originally developed for Java EE 7 which is tied to Java 7. Note thus that this indeed means that you don't at all need Java 8 when using EL Stream API, it will already work on Java 7.

Historically, the EL specification leads tried to design the EL Stream API as much as close to the Java 8's Stream API proposal as it was known at that time. Unfortunately among others the EL `Stream#join()` has slipped through because the `Collectors#joining()` was only added later.

In any case, you cannot use any of Java 8's Stream API functions such as `Collectors#xxx()` on the EL Stream methods. As said, the EL Stream API is entirely standalone. For collecting an EL Stream, only the `Stream#toArray()`, `Stream#toList()` and `Stream#reduce()` methods are available. See also chapter "[Operations on Collection Objects](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-el004.html)" in Java EE tutorial and chapter 2.3 "Collection Operations" of the [EL 3.0 specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/el-3_0-fr-eval-spec/EL3.0.FR.pdf).

So, in EL Stream API, your best bet in order to collect a stream by joining the strings, or any other custom collector, is to use `Stream#reduce()`. Below is an example for your specific case:

```
<div>${myList.stream().map(e -> e.stringValue).reduce((l, r) -> l += ', ' += r).get()}</div>
```

Note that I took the opportunity to simplify `${e.getStringValue()}` as `${e.stringValue}` as it basically represents a bean property in EL.

Comment: If a put the code in my own class an call it from within the EL expression, it's gonna work. Which is a shame, because it means it could execute the right code, but just because it has it's own API it won't.